# ¿como coloreo de blanco el menu hamburguesa?

Tags: html, css

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="Width-device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie-edge">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,600" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-hWVjflwFxL6sNzntih27bfxkr27PmbbK/iSvJ+a4+0owXq79v+lsFkW54bOGbiDQ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/responsive.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- navegador -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-transparent navbar-expand-lg sticky-top mr-auto">
        <button class="navbar-toggler button-toggle toggler-example white" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
          aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">MENU
          <span class="white navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          <span class="white navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          <span class="white navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#home" id="btn-home">HOME</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#album" id="btn-album">ALBUM</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#nosotros" id="btn-nosotros">NOSOTROS</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#contacto" id="btn-contacto">CONTACTO</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
      <!-- encabezado o portada -->
        <header>
          <div class="header-bg" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5">
            <div class="hero">
             </div>
          </div>
        </header>
  </body>
</html>
```

quiero lograr algo como esto y no estoy pudiendo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

podrias hacerlo de la siguiente manera:
En el HTML.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Color CSS</title>
</head>
<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg menu">

        <button class="navbar-toggler btn-menu" id="btn-menu" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav"
            aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="">Item</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Y en la hoja de estilos:

```
.menu
{
    background: #333;
}

.btn-menu
{
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 25px;
}

.nav-link
{
    color: #FFF;
}
```

Obtendrias algo asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya en ti quedaría adaptarlo a como lo quieres, para el icono estoy usando fontawesome pero puedes usar cualquier otro servicio. Espero sea de ayuda. Un Saludo

Answer (score 0):

Saludos podrias hacer algo como esto:

```css
body { background: black !important; 
}

.white{
 color:white
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>



   <!-- navegador -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-transparent navbar-expand-lg sticky-top mr-auto">
        <button class="navbar-toggler button-toggle toggler-example white" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
          aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">MENU
          <span class="white navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          <span class="white navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          <span class="white navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link white" href="#home" id="btn-home">HOME</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link white" href="#album" id="btn-album">ALBUM</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link white" href="#nosotros" id="btn-nosotros">NOSOTROS</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link white" href="#contacto" id="btn-contacto">CONTACTO</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
      <!-- encabezado o portada -->
        <header>
          <div class="header-bg" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5">
            <div class="hero">
             </div>
          </div>
        </header>


    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Si te fijas tan solo ocupe la clase CSS white, la misma que tiene el color deseado, de allí puedes ir agregando mas funcionalidades, espero te sirva y suerte..!!

**Actualizacion**
Para poder agregar el efecto Hamburguesa al menu seria algo asi:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.php">Acerca</a></li>
        <li><a href="#portfolio">Portafolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.php">Contacto</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Espero te sirva..!!

Comment: no se me pone blanco no se que pasa!

Comment: quiza estas usando estilos css que provocan ese error

Comment: ¿como cuales serian? porque si le puse color: white !important;

Comment: fijate que a las opciones de tu menu agregue tambn la clase white:...<a class="nav-link white" href="#nosotros" id="btn-nosotros">NOSOTROS</a>
            </li>....

Comment: si pero siguen sin aparecer los tres palitos blancos :(

Comment: @Ceci_Eiruweb revisa mi respuesta ya la actualize

Comment: ahora no me aparecen los elementos de lista li

Comment: con ese codigo que pusiste solo me aparece una barra lisa

Comment: @Ceci_Eiruweb lo que aparece es el boton para expandir la barra de navegacion; este es un componente de Bootstrap

Comment: no me aparece nada con ese codigo :(

Comment: tampoco me funcionan los mr-auto ni ml-auto que puede estar pasando?

Comment: @Ceci_Eiruweb Segun lo que estoy viendo, el ejemplo de arriba esta utilizando Bootstrap 3, si tu estas usando clases como `mr-auto` y similares, quiere decir que estas usando la version 4 de Bootstrap, asi que asegurate de cambiar la version a la que necesitas usar

Comment: aah si era eso una confusion de versiones, gracias